# Can I add a temporary column with auto-incremented values to my SQL query to complement my for loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm working on a school register system. I have an array of ones and zeroes prepared to update my students' presence/absence column. I want to insert the array values one row after another with a loop:

```
$arr = [1,0,1,1,1,0] // etc
for ($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
  $presence = $arr[$i];
  $conn->query("UPDATE attendance SET presence='$presence' WHERE id = '$i'");
}
```

But obviously my table has no such id column that would correspond to my $i variable. My aim is to update rows based on the user-selected month.

```
UPDATE attendance SET presence='$presence' WHERE monthname(date)='September';
```

I'd like to be able to create a temporary column with auto-incremented id numbers like in the first example so that I could use the for loop to insert the array contents. Is something like that possible?

Comment: If you don't have an `id` column, how do you know which `presence` flag corresponds to which student?

Comment: I do have id column in the attendance table but it's not sequential when insert based on month. I arranged it so that the ordering of the array elements corresponds exactly to the rows when I pull them out. It's not ideal but it works

Comment: So you want to create a data structure to hold data before you do a SQL Query.....

Comment: That won't work in the long run. SQL tables are *unordered*, so there is *no* guarantee that rows will be updated in the order you originally inserted them into the table. It's not even guaranteed that they will be read out in that order. You need to add a permanent `id` or similar column asap before you get too far down this path.

Comment: Ideally you would use a foreign key from your `attendance` table to your `students` table; those key values should then be the keys to your `$arr` array.

Comment: I do have that foreign key however I didn't realize I could link the column values to the array keys! Thanks a lot I'm back on track :)

Comment: @JakubJenč no worries - I'm glad that helped.

Comment: Also, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries